# Retrieving image from MySQL Database with CodeIgniter without using the upload library. Is it possible?

Tags: php, mysql, image, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

What I want to do is upload an image to my sql database using an html form and then retrieving it from the database to display it. I`ll show you some code so you can understand what I am trying to do.

***1st EDIT:*** Just linking an image to show the database table I am uploading the image to. The row type is blob --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sntk4.jpg in the code below I edited out the other rows of the DB table, but code for them is actually in.

This is the form that is uploading the image:

```
<form method="POST" action="/~gd339/ci/index.php/Add/postEvent/<?php echo $societyId ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Event image: <input type="file" name="image"/> <br>
    <input type="submit" name="POST" value="Post Event!" class = "unique"/>
```

What it does is that it posts the data to the `postEvent` controller:

```
        public function postEvent($society_id) {

            $this->load->model('Events_model');
                $image = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
            $this->Events_model->addEvent($image);

        }
```

Note that to get the image from the form, I am using `$image = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);` data retrieved using post is then sent to `addEvent` in my model:

```
        public function addEvent ($image) {
        $image1 = $this->db->escape($image);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO events (event_image) VALUES ($image1)";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        }
```

To retrieve the image I am using an image tag with a `src` that calls a function in the controller:

```
<img src="http://dragon.maple.as.re/~gd339/ci/index.php/add/getEventImage/<?php echo $row['event_id'] ?>">
```

```
        public function getEventImage($event_id){

                $this->load->model('Societies_model');
                $image = $this->Societies_model->getEventImage($event_id);
                header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
                print($image);
        }
```

code for `getEventImage`:

```
        public function getEventImage($event_id) {
            $data = '';
            $sql = "SELECT event_image FROM events WHERE event_id = $event_id";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            if ($query->num_rows()) {
                $data = $query->row_array();
                $data = $data['MA_PHOTO'];
                $query->free_result();
            }
            return $data;
        }
```

This results in the image just not showing up. I have been reading other examples here on stackoverflow and all of them, except for 1, use the CI upload library to do what I am trying to do. Is the library the only way to retrieve images using CI or is there something wrong in my code preventing the images to appear when called?

Thanks a lot to whoever will have the patience to go through my code. I know it is a lot but it is the first time I am using CI so im still learning.

Comment: `$image = file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);` use `move_uploaded_file()` or `is_uploaded_file()` at least.  `This is useful to help ensure that a malicious user hasn't tried to trick the script into working on files upon which it should not be working`

Comment: What type of field are you storing it in `blob` etc.  If it's not a binary capable field you'll have some issues....  `Is the library the only way to retrieve images using CI` - images existed in Databases long before CI had an upload library, I re-did a site made in 2000 (probably in 2009) that had more than 300Gb of image data in the DB (it wasn't fun) - but it wasn't CI either and the images worked just fine. Personally I don't like storing image data in the DB due to past experiences (like the above).  It's not a pleasant experience moving a DB of that size.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Sorry forgot to mention that! Yes the type of field that I am storing the images in is a ```blob```.  Thanks for the ```move_uploaded_file()``` suggestion I'll change that :). To be fair it is the first time I am dealing with a database as well so I still don't know from experience what is the best procedure to store image files! I was just trying to do my best and it is just a project for one of my unviersity modules so I am not too concerned about storing images in my DB for now. Thank you for telling me though, I'll definitely take that into account in the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a similar process without using CI_Upload.

A useful debug is, using some db tool, save the blob to a file and try to display it (using mspaint, image viewer, etc...)

Before I save the image on database, I use the following function to resize (as I don't need it big) and convert(ensure) that it is a jpeg.

```
private function get_image_resized($data){
  $data = smart_resize_image (
          null,
          $data,
          250,
          0,
          true,
          'return');
  $temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'ImageResize');
  imagejpeg($data, $temp_file, 100);
  $data = file_get_contents($temp_file);
  unlink($temp_file);
  return $data;
}
```

`smart_resize_image` can be found [here](https://github.com/Nimrod007/PHP_image_resize/blob/master/smart_resize_image.function.php):

To display the image

```
function imagem($cd_produto){
    $im_produto = $this->produto_model->get_imagem ( $cd_produto );

    header ( "Content-type:image/jpeg" );

    echo $im_produto;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I got some help from my supervisor and after like 2 hours and analyzing the image as you suggested, especially its binary code, we figured out that the image was being uploaded, encoded and visualized properly as a jpeg but what was preventing it from being displayed was... some whitespace that I had at the beginning and end of the controller. Some code here to  explain what I mean:                                                 ```   <--- _whitespace being uploaded with the image_  <?php 
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');  }
?> _whitespace_  --->    ```

Comment: Glad it helped!